# How to Change Go version in GitHub Codespace?

Tags: go, github, version

Here is the thing: by default, the go version is the latest in GitHub codespace, but I want to change it to an older one, how should I do to achieve this?

I've read a lot of articles, but none seems to be quite relevant, maybe it's too simple? I do not really know.

Comment: As an option, gvm allows you to switch between different go versions: https://github.com/moovweb/gvm